# Multiprocessing TypeError 'str' Object is not callable

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a limited understanding of python's multiprocessing library and this might be a dumb question, but here goes.

I am trying to write a program that utilizes multiprocessing to keep a connection alive that times out ever 30 minutes. Thus, you have to touch the server every 29 minutes. My goal is to write a connection_worker, and its only job is to sleep for 29 minutes, and wake up and touch the server then go back to sleep. I'm using a global connection object so I don't have to pass the object between the workers. I simply want each work isolated doing its required work. The worker thread is going to be the heavy lifter that will run on a different sleep time than the  connection thread its sleep can ranger from 24 hours to 6 minutes. Thus I want to start each as a process using multiprocessing and just have the processes access the global connection variable.

```
import multiprocessing
import atexit
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
from pyVmomi import vim
import time
from monitor import *
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from decimal import *
import cx_Oracle


global vcenter_connection 
current_time = ''

hostname = ''
username = ''
password = ''
vcenter_connection = SmartConnect(host = hostname,user = username,pwd = password)
atexit.register(Disconnect, vcenter_connection) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='do_work', target=do_work())
    #connection_service = multiprocessing.Process(name='connection_worker', target=connection_worker())
    jobs = ['worker_1()', 'connection_service()']
    for i,job in enumerate(jobs):
         i = multiprocessing.Process(name=job, target = job)
         i.start()

def connection_worker():
   while True:
      current_time = vcenter_connection.CurrentTime()
      print current_time
      time.sleep(29*60)

def do_work():
   while True:
      if vcenter_connection:
         print "You still have connection.. Sleeping for 5 minutes"
         time.sleep(5*60)
      else:   
         print "no connection"
```

The Console Print Out:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 21175)
job
worker_1()
job
connection_service()
Process worker_1():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Process connection_service():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The new code works but it sleeps all of the movement on time.sleep, I need both connection service and do_work to work in unison. That way connection_service is always running. Should I use a different method to alarm when 29 minutes is reached, but then how to I sleep the worker thread independently of that one, is it possible to sleep both independently with multiprocessing?

```
import time
from decimal import *
import cx_Oracle


global vcenter_connection 
current_time = ''

hostname = ''
username = ''
password = ''
vcenter_connection = SmartConnect(host = hostname,user = username,pwd = password)
atexit.register(Disconnect, vcenter_connection) 



def connection_service():
   while True:
      current_time = vcenter_connection.CurrentTime()
      print current_time
      time.sleep(29*60)

def do_work():
   while True:
      if vcenter_connection:
         print "You still have connection.. Sleeping for 5 minutes"
         time.sleep(5*60)
      else:   
         print "no connection"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='do_work', target=do_work())
    #connection_service = multiprocessing.Process(name='connection_worker', target=connection_worker())
    jobs = [('worker_1()', do_work), ('connection_service()', connection_service)]
    for job in jobs:
         i = multiprocessing.Process(name=job[0], target = job[1])
         i.start()
```

Comment: There's no need to use `enumerate(jobs)` in your for loop. You're not using the index (`i`) that gets returned at all. In fact, you're just overwriting it with the `Process` object returned by the call to `multiprocessing.Process`. Just use `for job in jobs:`

Comment: ah, your right thank you so much for pointing that out, I was going to enumerate and use i but ended up not using it. Didn't even think to change it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `multiprocessing.Process` function objects. You're passing it strings:

```
jobs = ['worker_1()', 'connection_service()']  # Strings.
for i,job in enumerate(jobs):
     i = multiprocessing.Process(name=job, target = job)
```

This should instead be:

```
jobs = [worker_1, connection_service]
for job in jobs:
     i = multiprocessing.Process(target=job)
```

Where `worker_1` and `connection_service` are functions defined at the top-level of your module.

If you want to preserve the `name` you're currently providing, you can make your list a list of tuples:

```
jobs = [('worker_1()', worker_1), ('connection_service()', connection_service)]
for job in jobs:
     i = multiprocessing.Process(target=job[1], name=job[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `multiprocessing.Process()` expects a `function` for parameter `target`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='do_work', target=do_work())
    #connection_service = multiprocessing.Process(name='connection_worker', target=connection_worker())

    # Now jobs contain functions and not strings
    jobs = [worker_1, connection_service]
    for i,job in enumerate(jobs):
         i = multiprocessing.Process(target = job)
         i.start()
```

Comment: I see, I was trying to pass the function name as a string object but I guess you can't do that. You guys were a big help I don't have enough rep to +1 but +1500 to you guys thanks.